# I receive an error message while creating my first woocommerce theme. The error message it type in the discription

Tags: php, xampp, wordpress-theming

I receive the following error message when creating woocommerce theme. 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_tmplate_directory_url() in C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-content\themes\woocommercetheme\functions.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(288): load_stylesheets('') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-includes\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-includes\script-loader.php(2667): do_action('wp_enqueue_scri...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(288): wp_enqueue_scripts('') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-includes\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-includes\general-template.php(2879): do_action('wp_head') #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-content\themes\woocommercetheme\header.php(7): wp_head() #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-includes\template.php(722): r in C:\xampp\htdocs\premier\wp-content\themes\woocommercetheme\functions.php on line 7
There has been a critical error on your website.

Answer (score 1):

Just misspelling problem! the correct code is:

```
get_template_directory_uri()
```